# File content matching - shopping list program

Tags: python

I'm working on a shopping list comparison program. The thinking is to match a CSV that just contains the name of a person and the amounts, like this:

```
name, potatoes, jam, beer, ice cream
Steve,2,6,2,5
Doreen,0,1,4,2
```

to one line txt. files formatted like this:
`beer,jam,ice cream,potatoes,jam,beer,ice cream,jam,ice cream,jam,ice cream,jam,potatoes,jam,ice cream`

The output in this example would be that the .txt file is equal to Steve (ie. according to the CSV Steve bought two potatoes, and the .txt lists potatoes twice, and so forth for all the other items he bought). The goal is to find whose shopping list is described in the .txt - and with the caveat that sometimes there is no match at all.

There are multiple CSV files and multiple .txt files, and the specific files used in the comparison are specified by the user as command line arguments (one for the CSV, one for the .txt). There are also two types of CSVs, with different headings in each (ie. one has, say, five shopping items, whereas the other have ten), so my solution needs to work regardless of which CSV is chosen. The .txt files are always formatted the same though.

How do I go about doing the actual comparison and then determining whose list it is?
I've tried messing around with `max(len)` a bit but I basically only manage to find the longest characters, not finding the individual occurrence of each word. The next step would be to compare the count of `beer` in the .txt to the number under `row[beer]` in the CSV. Would I need to create an array in which all of this is stored? Or are there faster ways, to just compare the two? Should I use `.fieldnames?`

I've tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
for field in fields:
str_length = len(field)
for i in range(1, len(sequence)+1):
    if (s[i:i+STR_length]==field):
        temp_count += 1
```

Comment: You read the txt file into a dict with keys as the names of products and values the count of products. Then you compare counts with proper counts from CSV file and see if all of them match. If this a school assignment?

Comment: Yes, for school. What is the best way to compare the dict counts with the CSV counts?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a key and value to the two lists with a dictionary:

```
data = ['name', 'potatoes', 'jam', 'beer', 'ice cream']
data_1 = ['Steve', '2', '6', '2', '5']

diction = dict(zip(data, data_1))
print(diction)
```

This sets the Key:Value pair.

```
{'name': 'Steve', 'potatoes': '2', 'jam': '6', 'beer': '2', 'ice cream': '5'}
```

To search for a key or value you can use dictionary comprehension:

```
search = input('Search: ')
result = {i: k for i, k in diction.items() if k == search or i == search}
print(result)
```

Which will output the key:value to your search term if it exists in the dictionary.

```
Search: name
{'name': 'Steve'}
```

Comment: Would this work if the keys are different in each CSV?

Comment: Yes it will set a key and value to everything from one list to the other. So if you had `[1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5]` in a list and `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` in another `dict(zip(list_1, list_2))` creates `{1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d', 5:'e'}`

Comment: Ok. So you're saying that I need to set an example from a real life CSV/.txt pair, and then the program will understand the relationships in the remaining files?

Comment: Yes it will pair anything you put in your list and the search will return what is associated with that list via its key or value. Just pass the cvs line by line and refresh the lists every time data is passed through

Answer (score 0):

For the one line .txt-files, you might want to use `Counter`.
Read your text file into a list or a numpy array. Let's call it `shopping_list`.
Now with your example:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> count_items = Counter(shopping_list)
>>> count_items
Counter({'jam': 6, 'ice cream': 5, 'potatoes': 2, 'beer': 2})
```

Now, if you want to get the counts of single items you can do:

```
>>> count_items["jam"]
6
```

You can also get the number of items:

```
>>> len(count_items)
4
```

I hope this already helps. Once you share more of the code you already have, I or someone else can also help with the rest I think.

EDIT:
And when you also make dictionaries out of your CSV (one for each line), you can compare them.
E.g. you have a dictionary

```
>>> diction
{'name': 'Steve', 'potatoes': '2', 'jam': '6', 'beer': '2', 'ice cream': '5'}
```

you can do

```
>>> name = diction.pop()
>>> name
'Steve'
>>>> diction
{'potatoes': 2, 'beer': 2, 'jam': 6, 'ice cream': 5}
```

Then you can compare if

```
>>> count_items == diction
True
```